# Unwrap optional value

Tags: ios, swift

I am fetching JSON data from a server.

Here is my code:

```
let myPTYPEIntegerValue : NSInteger? = (allData as! NSDictionary ).value(forKey: "PTYPE") as? NSInteger
    if myPTYPEIntegerValue != nil{
        help.myPTYPE = String.init(describing: myPTYPEIntegerValue)
    }

    let myIdIntegerValue : NSInteger? = (allData as! NSDictionary ).value(forKey: "ID") as? NSInteger
    if myIdIntegerValue != nil{
        help.myId = String.init(describing: myIdIntegerValue)
    }                        

    let jsonIDIntegerValue : NSInteger? = (allData as! NSDictionary ).value(forKey: "UID") as? NSInteger
    if jsonIDIntegerValue != nil{
         help.myUID = String.init(describing: jsonIDIntegerValue!)
         print(help.myUID)
    }
```

But it is showing

```
Optional(3)
Optional(2930)
Optional(238)
```

How to unwrap the optional here? What is the problem with my code?

Comment: Unrelated but do not use `NSInteger` and `NSDictionary` in Swift. There are native types. And do not use `valueForKey:` unless you can explain why do you explicitly need KVC in this case.

Answer (score 6):

You can use optional binding to unwrap the optional:

```
if let jsonIDIntegerValue = jsonIDIntegerValue {
    // jsonIDIntegerValue is now a non-optional local constant
    help.myUID = String(jsonIDIntegerValue)
    print(help.myUID)
}
```

This gets rid of the need for force-unwrapping. See the [Swift Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) for more information (look for the *Optional Binding* section).

Comment: This is, by far, the best answer. It shows how to properly unwrap the Optional, and removes the wrong use of `String(describing:)`. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

`help.myUID` is an **optional**. You should unwrap it while printing:

```
print(help.myUID!)
```

Note that in this case, you can safely unwrap implicitly, because you checked that the value is not `nil`.

Comment: Although safe in this case, force unwrapping is really inelegant.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking for `nil` and then using optional anyway, like you do

```
if myIdIntegerValue != nil{
    help.myId = String.init(describing: myIdIntegerValue)
}
```

you should rather use `if let` syntax, like so

```
if let myIdIntegerValue = myIdIntegerValue {
    help.myId = String.init(describing: myIdIntegerValue)
}
```

In that example, you shadow original `myIdIntegerValue : NSInteger!` variable with new `myIdIntegerValue : NSInteger`, which no longer is an optional

Comment: Do not use `String(describing: myIdIntegerValue)`, since that is just a longer version of writing `myIdIntegerValue.description`. And do not call `.init` directly, use the shorthand notation. Once `myIdIntegerValue` is non-optional, it is sufficient to call either `String(myIdIntegerValue)` or `"\(myIdIntegerValue)"`.

Answer (score 0):

You did not unwrapped the optional

This should look like

```
if myIdIntegerValue != nil{
   help.myId = String.init(describing: myIdIntegerValue)
}
```

This ...

```
if let myIdIntegerValueUnwrapped = myIdIntegerValue {
   help.myId = String.init(describing: myIdIntegerValueUnwrapped)
   print(myIdIntegerValue)
}
```

And any time when you want to get the value inside the optional.

Comment: `String(myIdIntegerValueUnwrapped)` would be better